# Kolmogorov-Smirnov Tests, D^- = 1

Tags: r, dice, kolmogorov-smirnov

I need some help with the interpretation of my ks.test output. 
I have 28 participants who each rolled three dice. Vektor g shows the resulting sum of rolls per person.

```
g <-c(16, 16, 18, 12, 12, 18, 18, 14,  9, 12, 15, 14, 13, 14, 10,  9, 12, 12, 11, 17, 17, 12,  8, 17, 13, 18, 15,  6)
```

I want to compare g to the actual distribution function. I used the following code to generate the "true" distribution function:

```
library("gtools")
library("dice")
v<-seq(1:15) 
for (i in 3:18) {
  p<-getEventProb(nrolls = 1, ndicePerRoll = 3, nsidesPerDie = 6, eventList= i, orderMatters = FALSE)  
  v[i]<-p
}
v<-v[-c(1,2)]
```

The following ks.test produces a D of 1 which can not be correct.

```
ks.test(g, cumsum(v), alternative = "less")
```

Can you tell me where I've made a mistake? Thank you so much for your answers!

Comment: why using `cumsum` of `v`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jimbou. ?ks.test sais y should be a distribution function, therefore I use cumsum(v) instead of v. Using v instead produces D=1 as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are comparing two very different things: a distribution of the roll totals (ranging from 3-18) and a *probability distribution* (ranging from 0-1):

```
> g
 [1] 16 16 18 12 12 18 18 14  9 12 15 14 13 14 10  9 12 12 11 17 17 12  8 17 13 18 15  6
> v
 [1] 0.00462963 0.01388889 0.02777778 0.04629630 0.06944444 0.09722222 0.11574074 0.12500000 0.12500000 0.11574074
[11] 0.09722222 0.06944444 0.04629630 0.02777778 0.01388889 0.00462963
```

So to the KS, these are obviously two very different things. Probably the easiest thing would be determine the frequency of each total from 3:18 in your empirical distribution (participant totals) and compare that with the expected probably distribution.

Comment: Hi Keith, thank you very much for your answer. ?ks.test sais: x should be a numeric vector of data values and y should be a cumulative distribution function. Also have a look at the example of the help article. Their x values are rnorm generated values (like my vector g) and y is a distribution function (like my cumsum(v). Actually this should work, or which mistake am I making here? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Hausladen, I believe that `y` can be either another set of values or a CDF _function_ (from the docs `y: either a numeric vector of data values, or a character string naming a cumulative distribution function or an actual cumulative distribution function such as ‘pnorm’.`) What you are passing in this case is the output of such a function - if you want to go that route, then you will need to construct a function that behaves like `pnorm` and pass that in for `y`.